# Determine a menu choice without using logical operators, relational operators, or selection constructs

Tags: c

I am working on a program for one of my classes, and it contains a simple menu like this:

```
Please choose an option below:
--------------------------------
1) Calculate with just gravity
2) Calculate with net force
3) Calculate with just drag
```

Now, usually it would be quite simple to determine what the menu choice is, but we are not allowed to use logical operators, relational operators, or selection constructs. I've been trying to use modulus, but to no avail. Is this even possible? We essentially can only use +, -, *, /, and %. As well as simple variables. Thank you!

Comment: Is `switch` allowed? It just does normal comparison internally though.

Comment: Sadly not! I'm so used to using `if` and `switch` statements.

Comment: How about an array of function pointers?

Comment: @dbush not that either. It's really quite intriguing. We can only use +, -, *, /, and %. As well as simple variables.

Comment: Is this true: "net force = gravity + drag"? If so, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume net force = gravity + drag, and input is one of 1, 2, or 3.

```
net_force = gravity + drag
result = (2 - choice) * gravity + net_force + (choice - 2) * drag
result = result / (choice % 2 + 1)
```

- choice = 1 => (gravity + gravity + drag - drag) / (2) => gravity
- choice = 2 => (net_force) / (1) => net_force
- choice = 3 => (-gravity + gravity + drag + drag) / (2) => drag

All of `+-*/%` are used .

Answer (score 0):

Well use String to take input and compare them using `strcmp` function [Here is how to compare strings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

**Note : I'm using if/else but not using any logical operator, hope this helps**

```
// Take string input
if(strcmp("1",input))
     // Calculate with just gravity
else if(strcmp("2",input))
     // Calculate with net force
else if(strcmp("3",input))
     // Calculate with just drag
```