# How to make a logical selection using calculations in c?

Tags: c, mathematical-expressions

I am helping my daughter with an intro to c programming assignment, and her homework contains a simple menu like this:

```
Please choose an option below:
------------------------------
1. Linear time
2. Logarithmic time
3. Exponential time
```

Now, usually it would be quite simple to determine what the menu choice is, but she is not allowed to use logical operators, relational operators, bitwise operators, or selection constructs. We have been trying to use modulus, but to no avail. Is this even possible? She can essentially only use `+, -, *, /, and %`. As well as simple variables.

The only solution we have come up with so far is using equality:

```
(choice==1)*n + (choice==2)*log(n) + (choice==3)*(n*n)
```

where `n` is the size of the data set to sort, but that is not allowed.

Comment: Logan asked [a comparable question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41971937/7868908); however, his chosen solution is expressed in terms of special variables. We are seeking a more general solution to the problem.

Comment: Can you use bitwise operators?

Comment: Nope, no bitwise operators are allowed.

Comment: Sorry, dude, you're out of luck. Ask the advisor about the reason of this - such a restriction is highly unreasonable to me.

Comment: @iBug, we couldn't agree more. In industry, I only do it when you have a legitimate optimization requirement. All other times, we should write code that is clear and easily understandable.

Comment: Call via an array of 3 function pointers.

Comment: What is required to happen if a value outside the range 1-3 is entered?

Comment: The Instructor says that the values will only ever be 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: @ChrisHeady It may not be an optimization, it depends. Also, it is rare to need to write branchless code.

Comment: @iBug It is quit [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54502949/how-to-make-a-logical-selection-using-calculations-in-c/54503105#comment95810009_54502949) for select values of `choice`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> only use +, -, *, /, and %

Hmm - strange restriction

---

Instead of `(choice==1)*foo1 + (choice==2)*foo2 + (choice==2)*foo3`

Use multiplication, division to effect the `==` for select values of `choice` 1,2,3.

```
(choice-2)*(choice-3)/((1-2)*(1-3)) * foo1 + 
(choice-1)*(choice-3)/((2-1)*(2-3)) * foo2 + 
(choice-1)*(choice-2)/((3-1)*(3-2)) * foo3
```

Notice  `(choice-2)*(choice-3)/((1-2)*(1-3))` is 1 when `choice==1` otherwise 0.

---

This technique is like [The Lagrange method](http://practicalcryptography.com/miscellaneous/machine-learning/fitting-polynomial-set-points/) in polynomial curve fitting.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
int (* choice[3])(int n) = { linear, log, exp };
```

where each is a function of n returning an int.  Call via

```
 v = choice[I](n);
```

Comment: `choice[I](n)` is enough

Answer (score 0):

If the calculations are a bit more complicated it might be difficult to do it in one operation. Then use function pointers:

```
double linear(double x)
{
    double result;
    /* some cacls */
    return result;
}

double logarithmic(double x)
{
    double result;
    /* some cacls */
    return result;
}

double expotential(double x)
{
    double result;
    /* some cacls */
    return result;
}


double (*calcfunc[])(double) = {linear, logarithmic, expotential};


double calc(int choice, double x)
{
    return calcfunc[choice](x);
}
```

I hope that the arrays are allowed :)
Very strange requirements - it does not teach anything, except bad practices. The arguments and return types are example of course.